# Creating CLPlacemark with custom values for testing

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, clplacemark

I have an application that moves `CLPlacemark` objects around and uses them, and I would like to unit-test several components that interact with them. To do this, I would like to be able to stub out calls to real reverse-geolocation from MapKit with methods that produce mock `CLPlacemark`s with known values.

`CLPlacemark` only has one initializer (copy initializer). But in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLPlacemark), it says:

> Placemark objects are typically generated by a CLGeocoder object, although you can also create them explicitly yourself.

However, most of the members are read-only, so I'm not sure how to create one with custom values. Is it possible to set internal properties in this way in Swift? If not, any ideas as to what they mean in the above citation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use OCMock (http://ocmock.org) to stub out calls to create stub CLPlacemark objects, and stub out their getter methods with your own values.

```
id userDefaultsMock = OCMClassMock([CLPlacemark class]);

// set it up to return a specific value when stringForKey: is called
OCMStub([userDefaultsMock property]).andReturn(customValue);
```

Comment: thanks for that suggestion. I have been avoiding use of OCMock because it's strictly designed with ObjcC in mind, but I bet I can find my own way (i.e. subclasses or something) to stub out property getters.

Answer (score 0):

Some archeology here, but here is a working answer, as I just had this need

```swift
    public static func mock(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String) -> CLPlacemark {
        let mkPlacemark = MKPlacemark(
            coordinate: coordinate,
            addressDictionary: ["name": name]
        )
        return CLPlacemark(placemark: mkPlacemark)
    }
```

Usage:

```swift
let placemark = CLPlacemark.mock(
    coordinate: CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), name: "mock-name"
)
```